# web service error ' it does not have a parameterless constructor '

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wse, web-services-enhancements

I've created a web service , which can a method to set the user credential using `Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol`. The sample code is :

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Sub ClientCredential1(Of TSecurityToken As SecurityToken)_
         (ByVal UserCred As Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameToken)

        Dim cProxy As New Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol()
        cProxy.SetClientCredential(UserCred)
    End Sub
```

When I run the web service it gives this error:

> "Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameToken cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor."

Does any one know where is the problem ?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow! If you'd like to format you posts so they are more readable and more likely to be answered, please read the [StackOverflow Markup Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Good Luck with your Question!

Comment: I take it to mean that to initialize or create a new variable of type UserCred, you must send something along with the New() constructor. IE, Dim myCreds as new userCred(param1, param2).  Since I don't know for sure, I am not posting this as an answer, but I would start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem here is that the class `Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameToken` doesn't have a parameter-less constructor. It's got 3 of them, but they all demand a parameter. [UsernameToken constructors on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services3.security.tokens.usernametoken.usernametoken.aspx).

- `UsernameToken (XmlElement)`
- `UsernameToken (String, String)`
- `UsernameToken (String, String, PasswordOption)`

The problem is that during deserialization, XmlSerializer calls the parameterless constructor to create an instance of that class. It can't deserialize a type that doesn't have a parameterless constructor.

I get the sense there's not much you can do to work around this problem. I'd only suggest creating a partial class, and implementing that zero-param constructor yourself.

```
'ensure namespacing is correct.
Public Partial Class UsernameToken
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub    
End Class
```

Comment: Since UsernameToken is defined in a referenced assembly, I don't think you can add a constructor using a partial class definition... I think that only works when you have the source code for all parts of the class.

Comment: @Richard: I figured as much. It was a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

p. campbell is right, it's because the XmlSerializer requires a parameterless constructor.

I don't know WSE, but from looking at [this post](http://aleemkhan.wordpress.com/2007/09/18/using-wse-30-for-web-service-authentication/) on Aleem's Weblog, I don't think the UsernameToken is supposed to be passed as a regular argument to a web method - it's supposed to be passed in the WS-Security SOAP headers. You get the proxy to pass it in the headers by calling [SetClientCredential()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa748225.aspx). Here's the example from the above blog post:

```
Dim oService As New WSETestService.ServiceWse

Dim U As New UsernameToken(“<User_Name>”, “<Password>”, PasswordOption.SendHashed)
oService.SetClientCredential(U)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a parameter of the type `Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameToken` in a web service, as it's not possible to serialise (or more specifically not possible to deserialise).

Create a class that just contains the data that you need to create a `UsernameToken` and use as parameter type. The client side would not create a real `UsernameToken` object anyway, there is a proxy class created from the WSDL information.